# Buttons dont work on iOS in Phonegap if I add jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery, ios, cordova

I build a hybrid app with native code and Phonegap 2.1. The app has 4 Javascript screens. The last Javascript screen has buttons to open the native coded Screens by using a navigationcontroller. I used `jQuery` Buttons and Javascript Buttons of all different kinds. It works if I dont use `jQuery` mobile.

But if I include the `jQuery` mobile files to the javascript file, all different buttons wont work any more. The strange thing is, that if i remove the `jQuery` includes in the second javascript screen and the third javascript screen, the `jQuery` mobile buttons in the 4th javascript screen work and look great, but the second javascript screen and the third javascript screen have no `jQuery` mobile and look now crappy.

It seems that phonegap caches the `jQuery` mobile files, what shouldnt be possible in html pages. I have a scrollview in the javascript sides, but I read, that the bug clicking button in combination with scrollview is fixed, and I tested it without scroll view and had the same problems. I also removed the childbrowser I had, but also without a result.

I tested it before with Phonegap 1.9 but there I have the same problems. I tested it with several browsers and there it works fine. Thanks for reading and thanks for the help. I'm a little bit desperate now.

Comment: one tip, try to organize you posts with paragraphs otherwise one opens it and just ignores

Comment: Can you post some code. Are you including the css for jQuery Mobile when including it?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />      
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no;" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="reset"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" id="layout" href="css/tiles.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="reset" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="reset" />

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="js/storage.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jm/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<script src="js/jm/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>`
```

Here the header from the second screen. I have organized all headers the same. If I remove the last line, where I include jquery.mobile.js, then the buttons in the html page which I open 2 screens later work.
This way I trigger my button

```
<a data-role="button" href="javascript:callNativePlugin();" value="Go to Player jQuery Button" data-theme="x" class="btnClose">Go to Player jQuery Button</a>
```

but a used several combinations to call the function and nothing worked.
This way I call the native function:

```
function callNativePlugin()
{
var returnSuccess = "success";
alert('call Native Function');
HelloPlugin.callNativeFunction( nativePluginResultHandler, nativePluginErrorHandler, returnSuccess );
}

function nativePluginResultHandler (result)
{
alert("SUCCESS: \r\n"+result );
}

function nativePluginErrorHandler (error)
{
alert("ERROR: \r\n"+error );
}
```

the alert is not called if the problem happens.